# weird mysql_fetch_array error

Tags: php, mysql

```
   if($_GET['confirm']){
        $coupon_id = $_GET['confirm'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE coupon_id = '$coupon_id'");
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $user_id = $rows['user_id'];
                $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchases_confirm VALUES(NULL,'$coupon_id','$user_id' ");
                if($query){
                    echo "inserting new values to database....done !";
                }
            }
        exit;
        }
```

and it outputs :  Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in...the weird thing that if i execute the query from the command line or phpmyadmin ,it works !!

Comment: Variables aren't expensive.  Make a new one for the internal query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reassign `$query` variable inside while with `mysql_fetch_array` using `$query`.

Should be:

```
   if($_GET['confirm']){
        $coupon_id = $_GET['confirm'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE coupon_id = '$coupon_id'");
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $user_id = $rows['user_id'];
                $query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchases_confirm VALUES(NULL,'$coupon_id','$user_id' ");
                if($query2){
                    echo "inserting new values to database....done !";
                }
            }
        exit;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because in you're while loop, you are overwriting the `$query` variable. You need to change the `$query` variable to something else. I generally use `$sub_query` So it looks like this:

```
if($_GET['confirm']){
$coupon_id = $_GET['confirm'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE coupon_id = '$coupon_id'");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $user_id = $rows['user_id'];
    $sub_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchases_confirm VALUES(NULL,'$coupon_id','$user_id' ");
    if($sub_query){
        echo "inserting new values to database....done !";
    }
}
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing `$query` inside the loop :`$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchases_confirm VALUES(NULL,'$coupon_id','$user_id' ");` and on the next iteration you are trying `mysql_fetch_array($query)`. Use a different variable for insert : `$another_quer = mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchases_confirm VALUES(NULL,'$coupon_id','$user_id' ");`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the query's failing. You lack any form of error checking, so you're essentially throwing away your chance to catch the error. Try rewriting the code like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());
```

which'll spit out the exact mysql error that caused the query to fail. Remember, even if the SQL statement itself is perfectly valid, there are many many other reasons why the query can fail. By failing to check for those potential error conditions, you've basically painted yourself into a corner.